# docker centos7 jenkins installation

Tags: docker, jenkins, installation, centos7

I have installed Centos:7 docker image inside Ubuntu,and I have successfully installed Java,but when I'm trying to add  the Jenkins repository to the yum repos, and install Jenkins from here I'm receiving an error.
bash: sudo: command not found

[jenins installation problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHcyp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your Screenshot says Sudo is not installed. So please install Sudo.
Try to login with su
$ su -
and install sudo

## apt-get install sudo

Comment: after installing sudo and wget the problem solved.Thanks a ton!